# How do I pass devise data to a React component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, react-rails

I'm trying to pass Devise data to a React component. Devise is set up correctly, but I can't figure out how to pass the current_user info as props to my react_component. the React props current_user keeps logging as non-existent. I'm using React v5.1 and React-Rails v2.4.

index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component 'Main', props: {current_user: @current_user} %>
```

_main.js.jsx

```
var Main = createReactClass({
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.current_user.id}
                <Header />
                <Body />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: It should be `<%= react_component 'Main', props: {current_user: current_user} %>` and not `<%= react_component 'Main', props: {current_user: @current_user} %>`

Comment: Tried this, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `props: {current_user: current_user}` instead of `props: {current_user: @current_user}`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like the following

```
<%= react_component 'Main', props: {current_user: current_user.to_json} %>
```

React side

```
var Main = createReactClass({
    getInitialState() {
    return {
      currentUser: this.props.current_user
    };
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.currentUser.id}
                <Header />
                <Body />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: you're missing `to_json`.

Comment: Tried this, still not working. I also tried calling {this.state.current_user.id} and that didn't work either.

Comment: I guess you're missing something else, Can you show your code with the new changes ?